# Weird frequency when plotting the recorded sound

Tags: java, android, matlab, audio, signal-processing

I have a generated noise stored in a WAV file, I'm going to play it on an Android smartphone with speaker and record the sound and save it as another WAV file using the same smartphone(just 2 separate threads, 1 for playing, 1 for recording). I can successfully get the recorded WAV file. But when I plot both WAV files in Matlab, I have a weird difference between 2 plots, [image: The button one is the recorded signal]

As you can see, the recorded signal has much higher frequency than the original signal. I cannot distinguish between these 2 WAV files using my own ears. Can someone tell me what exactly causes this difference? Thank you!
[My original wav file is here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6mDg0MzJ8fpa1hZRV9CME5EaGM/edit?usp=sharing),    [My recorded WAV file is here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6mDg0MzJ8fpQlEwV2FsaVZWRHM/edit?usp=sharing), and my code for recording the sound is:

```
private int bufferSizeInBytes = 0;  
 private int audioSource = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;  
    private static int sampleRateInHz = 48000;   
    private static int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;  
    private static int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;  
      
      private void creatAudioRecord() {  
          
            bufferSizeInBytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRateInHz,  
                    channelConfig, audioFormat);  
        
            audioRecord = new AudioRecord(audioSource, sampleRateInHz,  
                    channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSizeInBytes);  
        }  
      
      class AudioRecordThread implements Runnable {  
            @Override  
            public void run() {  
                writeDateTOFile2();
                copyWaveFile(AudioName, NewAudioName);
            }  
        }  
private void writeDateTOFile2(byte[] audiodata) {  
      
            FileOutputStream fos = null;  
            int readsize = 0;  
            try {  
                File file = new File(AudioName2);  
                if (file.exists()) {  
                    file.delete();  
                }  
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            } catch (Exception e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
                    try {  
                        fos.write(audiodata);  
                    } catch (IOException e) {  
                        e.printStackTrace();  
                    }  
                
             
            try {  
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }  
        

        
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename, String outFilename) {  
            FileInputStream in = null;  
            FileOutputStream out = null;  
            long totalAudioLen = 0;  
            long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;  
            long longSampleRate = sampleRateInHz;  
            int channels = 1;  
            long byteRate = 16 * sampleRateInHz * channels / 8;  
            byte[] data = new byte[bufferSizeInBytes];  
           
            try {  
                in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);  
                out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);  
                totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();  
                totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;  
                WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,  
                        longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);  
                while (in.read(data) != -1) {  
                    out.write(data);  
                }  
                in.close();  
                out.close();  
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            } catch (IOException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
          }
           
        }  
        
       
        private void WriteWaveFileHeader(FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,  
                long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels, long byteRate)  
                throws IOException {  
            byte[] header = new byte[44];  
            header[0] = 'R'; // RIFF/WAVE header  
            header[1] = 'I';  
            header[2] = 'F';  
            header[3] = 'F';  
            header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);  
            header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);  
            header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);  
            header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);  
            header[8] = 'W';  
            header[9] = 'A';  
            header[10] = 'V';  
            header[11] = 'E';  
            header[12] = 'f'; // 'fmt ' chunk  
            header[13] = 'm';  
            header[14] = 't';  
            header[15] = ' ';  
            header[16] = 16; // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk  
            header[17] = 0;  
            header[18] = 0;  
            header[19] = 0;  
            header[20] = 1; // format = 1  
            header[21] = 0;  
            header[22] = (byte) channels;  
            header[23] = 0;  
            header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);  
            header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);  
            header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);  
            header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);  
            header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);  
            header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);  
            header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);  
            header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);  
            header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8); // block align  
            header[33] = 0;  
            header[34] = 16; // bits per sample  
            header[35] = 0;  
            header[36] = 'd';  
            header[37] = 'a';  
            header[38] = 't';  
            header[39] = 'a';  
            header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);  
            header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);  
            header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);  
            header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);  
            out.write(header, 0, 44);  
        }
```

And my code for plotting these 2 WAV files in Matlab is:

```
[wave,fs]=wavread('jamming3.wav'); 
wave=wave(:,[1]);
t=0:1/fs:(length(wave)-1)/fs;
 magnwave=abs(fft(wave));
 phasewave=angle(fft(wave));
 sub1_L=magnwave.*exp(i*phasewave);
 sub1_L=ifft(sub1_L);
 q=(abs(sub1_L).*cos(angle(sub1_L)))*(2^15-1);
 q=q(1000:length(q),1);
% plot(q);
% axis([44000,45000,-2^15+1,+2^15-1]);
 
 
 
test = 950;

t=0:1/fs:(length(wave)-1)/fs;
z = t([1],:);
wave1=wave(:,[1])*(2^15-1);
figure; hold on;
grid on;
box on;
plot(1:length(q), q,'-g','Displayname','Original noise');
%scatter(1:length(wave1), wave1,5, [1 0 0],'Displayname','Noise sample');
%scatter(1:length(q),q(:,1)-wave1,5,'Displayname','Error');
%axis([test,test+200,-40000,40000]);
axis([0,300,-40000,40000]);
hold on;
legend show;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

[wave,fs]=wavread('recorded noise2.wav'); 
wave=wave(:,[1]);
%wave=wave(1000:length(wave));
%sub1=sub1(1000:length(sub1));

t=0:1/fs:(length(wave)-1)/fs;
 magnwave=abs(fft(wave));
 phasewave=angle(fft(wave));
 sub1_L=magnwave.*exp(i*phasewave);
 sub1_L=ifft(sub1_L);
 q1=(abs(sub1_L).*cos(angle(sub1_L)))*(2^15-1);
 q1=q1(15252:length(q1),1);
% plot(q);
% axis([44000,45000,-2^15+1,+2^15-1]);
 
 
 offsets = 0;


t=0:1/fs:(length(wave)-1)/fs;
z = t([1],:);
wave1=wave(:,[1])*(2^15-1);
figure; hold on;
grid on;
box on;
plot(1:length(q1), q1*1.25,'-g','Displayname','Recovered signal');
%scatter(1:length(wave1), wave1,5, [1 0 0],'Displayname','Noise sample');
%scatter(1:length(q),q(:,1)-wave1,5,'Displayname','Error');
axis([offsets,offsets+300,-40000,40000]);
%axis([0,300,-40000,40000]);
hold on;
legend show;
```

Update#1: sorry for the confusion, the parts I'm plotting is the header I put in the WAV file for synchronization, so I can do further processing on the data following it.
[image: my plotted wave using voice recognization channel]

Update#2: I recently update my code to use voice recognization channel to record the sound, it looks better, but frequency is still the problem. My new recorded noise is also updated in the link above.

Update#3: I just displayed the exact size of these 2 wav files in matlab, by using size(x), and it shows that the array extracted from original file is about 100k, and the one from recorded wav file is only 50k, based on the face that these 2 files are of same size, I think this may be the problem. Is there anything wrong with my recording process?

Update#4: I just realized that the recorded wav file, which was generated by smartphone, cannot be directly played in matlab by wavplay() function, is it the reason? There may be some problem in my wav writing function above, but it is the standard way to generate a WAV file:(

Update#5: Knowing that 44.1 khz is supported by all devices, so I changed my original signal to 44.1 khz, still no good. :(

Comment: Would this be caused by the automatic gain control? Oh, and I definitely do hear a difference between the two.

Comment: @PurpleAlien I never heard of this term before, according to wikipedia, this may be the reason, how can I avoid this? thank you

Comment: @PurpleAlien I also noticed that if I play it on my Desktop, there is difference, but on my smartphone both wav files sound the same thing.

Comment: The files sounding the same is probably due to the relatively bad speaker compared to a desktop system or headphones. There also might be some filtering going on.

Comment: To disable the AGC, I believe there is an option to pick 'voice recognition' as a source instead of just Mic. EDIT: Try to put interger number 6 as audio source in AudioRecord().

Comment: Too late to edit my previous comment, but the '6' there comes from MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION

Comment: You seem to be recording in stereo. Your wav file contains only one channel. Do you need to record in mono?

Comment: It's been years since I did audio on computers, but if you have a signal like that, you're dealing with all sorts of harmonics introduced by the spectrum of the sound, which gets clipped by the lousy speaker (acting essentially as a bandpass filter). Additionally, you're probably also recording some echo, since the wavelength at 14kHz is only about an inch -- you could get echo within the phone itself. All of this is superimposed over the original signal, so that is what you get. It sounds the same in the phone, as you hear the distorted signal in both cases.

Comment: @323go that sounds reasonable, is there anyway I can get rid of the echo?

Comment: You could implement standard echo cancellation algorithms, since you know the source and can probably estimate the roundtrip time, but I don't know how feasible this is -- it really depends on your application. If the goal is to mix sound, you could do that on-device better than through the audio-path.

Comment: @323go  Can i just do this in Matlab? which algorithm do you recommend? Thank you!

Comment: It's been too long, sorry. We used an adaptive filter on a DSP. Not sure it works on a static source, this was for early VOIP.

Comment: Alright, since no one is able to locate the problem, so my conclusion is that it is all because of the current hardware constrains, thanks everyone for your concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if the sample rate specified by one or more of the files does not match the sample rate at which the data was recorded or is being played.